# JQuery datepicker doesn't work after input changed from readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I'm using this [datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) with an MVC3 application.

I want to have the input field as `readonly` until an edit button is clicked. When the field is then in focus I want to call the datepicker.

The following code works fine if the page loads with the input editable. However, when I add the readonly attribute, the datepicker doesn't appear once the edit button is clicked and the field is no longer readonly. What is stopping the datepicker from being called?

```
$("[id$='Date']:not([readonly])").datepicker({ format: "dd MM yyyy" })
        .focus(function () {
            $(this).on('changeDate', function () {
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
            })
        });
```

---

The code for changing the field from readonly to editable is as follows:

```
//enable editing and change button to "Update"
$("[id$='-edit']").click(function (e) {
    var myButton = e.target.id;
    //get text based on browser
    var txt = e.target.textContent || e.target.innerText;
    if (txt == 'Edit') {
        e.preventDefault();
        var myText = myButton.slice(0, (myButton.indexOf('-')));
        $('#' + myText).prop('readonly', false);
        e.target.textContent = 'Update';
        //added below for browser compatibility
        e.target.innerText = 'Update';
    }
    else {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    }
});
```

Razor and HTML generated by MVC:

Editable:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.reviewDate)

<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Review Date field is required." id="reviewDate" name="reviewDate" type="text" value="12 December 2013" class="valid">
```

Readonly:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.reviewDate, new { @readonly = "readonly" })

<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Review Date field is required." id="reviewDate" name="reviewDate" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="12 December 2013" class="valid">
```

The above readonly after the readonly attribute removed via the edit button code:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Review Date field is required." id="reviewDate" name="reviewDate" type="text" value="12 December 2013" class="valid">
```

### Solution

As per the accepted answer, I've changed the edit button code to assign the datepicker when the readonly attribute is removed.

This line...

```
$('#' + myText).prop('readonly', false);
```

...is now this:

```
$('#' + myText).prop('readonly', false).datepicker({ format: "dd MM yyyy" });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
$("[id$='Date']:not([readonly])").datepicker(...
```

does not assign the datepicker to elements that are readonly. If you change an element to remove the readonly attribute, you must then also assign the datepicker at that point.